# Any idea how to fix this Google Play policy violation?

Tags: android, google-play, admob, google-play-console

Honestly, I'm out of options. That's why I'm here. I'm hoping that maybe someone else has had a similar issue and knows what the problem might be.

Going on a month ago now, I tried to update my app. The only change I made was moving a temporary file from the external storage to the cache storage. When I uploaded it to Google Play, it was rejected for a "Interfering with Apps, Third-party Ads, or Device Functionality" policy violation (the policy has since been renamed to "Monetization and Ads policy").

I use Google Admob to serve a single interstitial ad after the user completes an operation. It only appears once and it will only appear every fifth time you use the app. So I thought maybe the issue was with the interstitial ad, so I changed it to a banner (which I've used on tons of other apps without issues) and it was again rejected for the same reason.

Then I tried removing the ads entirely. This included completely removing the Google Play services Admob dependency from my app. I resubmitted and it still got rejected. So I decided to file an appeal, since it's clearly a mistake with the Google Play Console.

The person responded with basically the same information that I got in the original email notifying me of the issue and said that I should be ok to resubmit the app. I tried, it failed, so they said to file another appeal. The next person I talked to for the second appeal again cut and paste the original violation email and said that if I think it's a mistake, I need to file another appeal. Five appeals later, I'm stuck in an infinite loop of filing an appeal just to be told to file another appeal.

Anyone had a similar issue and, better yet, have any idea on how to fix it? The people who respond the emails refuse to explain what the cause of the issue is (other than copying and pasting the paragraphs from the policy page) and don't offer any input about how I could go about fixing it.

I don't know what else to do.

Comment: I have the same issue exactly! Did you manage to solve this? Thanks

Comment: @EranKatsav Yes, I did get everything sorted. I'll post more information as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally get this resolved and I'm really surprised that I had to go through 5 different Google employees in order for one to point out the problem.

The original policy violation is my fault entirely. I made a typo in the code that caused a popup ad open when the app is launched. This triggers Google's test devices as a policy violation. I had meant for that to happen only every X numbers of time, but had changed that value during testing and forgot to change it back since my test device didn't erase the counter so I never noticed it.

However, my issue with the repeated violations was a Google Play Console issue. I don't use the other test tracks that they offer for uploading (internal test, alpha and beta). Since I'm the sole developer, I only ever use release.

But when it was uploaded to Google Play and the issue was detected, the app was moved to the internal test track. Therefore, when I uploaded a new version to release, the old version still on the internal test track was triggering the policy violation and automatically cancelling my release from being published on Google Play.

To solve this, I ended having to put the new version into the internal test track and then pushing that through the alpha and beta tracks to the release track once Google Play completed it's automated tests.

It took me more than two months of talking back and forth with Google reps to figure out the problem, so hopefully this can help someone out.

Comment: So the App in the "Internal Test Track" will also affect the production app?

My App in Production has not advertisement while the latest build I am testing in Internal Test Track comes with it. Google Play removed my App in the Production from Play Store.

Comment: @speedlight That was the issue in my specific case, yes. It was the internal track that was causing the issue, not the production track, but it still caused issues with policy violations on the production track. Pretty stupid if you ask me, since the internal track is for testing features and it may contain broken items, since it's not publicly available.

Comment: @ComputerWhiz About what you said "But when it was uploaded to Google Play and the issue was detected, the app was moved to the internal test track", would you tell us how do you know that? We cannot see versions in internal test track if we do not put them. Did Google employees tell that? 
If so, Google really waste many developers' time to solve their puzzle.

Answer (score 1):

Try This,

Remove Ads from app and remove dependencies also and rename the package of the app and try submitting as different app.

Let Me Know If It Works or not

Comment: I've already removed the ads and removed the dependencies, although I haven't tried renaming the package, so I'll have to try that and see if it helps. As for making a new listing, that would be disappointing since I already have users on my current listing. I have ratings too, all of which would be lost. Although, I can't help but feel that I'll be forced to do that anyway.